# How to insert values from an input into an array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms, input

I am a beginner in JavaScript. I have a table which shows details of a bill. Quantity can be filled in the form. Once I enter the quantities and submit the form, the bill will be calculated and display the price of each type, and the total. So how to insert values from input into an array?

```js
<!--//Script.js
document.writeln("<table name=\"bill\" style=\"text-align:center\"><tr><th>Ice cream type</th><th>Name</th><th>Unit Price</th><th>quantity</th><th>Total</th><tr>");
var type = ["vanilla", "chocolote", "mango", "Butterscotch"];
var data = [70, 60, 80, 100];

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  document.writeln("<tr><td id=\"dx\" width=" + 200 + "px>type " + (i + 1) + "</td><td width=" + 100 + "px>" + type[i] + "</td><td>" + data[i] + "</td><td><input type=text></td><td id=a></td></tr>");
}

document.writeln("<tr ></tr><td id=p1 colspan=4 style=\"text-align:right\">total</td><td ></td></table>");

function myfunc() {

}

//-->
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align:center">The Ice-Cream Shop</h1>
<center>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Script.js">
  </script>
  <p><input type=button value=submit> <input type=button value=clear onclick="myfunc()"></p>
  <p id=x></p>
</center>
```

Answer (score 3):

To add all the values of all the text inputs on a page into an array, you do the following:

```
var array = [];
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("input");
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    if(inputs[i].type == "text"){
        array[array.length] = inputs[i].value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've added a function `calculate()` which does the trick for you:

```
function calculate() {
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
  const arrayInputValues = Array.from(inputs).map(input => +input.value);
  console.log(arrayInputValues);
}
```

Complete it by performing the required calculations. Below is a code snippet with this function applied.

Input values are strings so you need to convert it to integers. That's done via "+" prefix.

```js
<!--//Script.js
document.writeln("<table name=\"bill\" style=\"text-align:center\"><tr><th>Ice cream type</th><th>Name</th><th>Unit Price</th><th>quantity</th><th>Total</th><tr>");
var type=["vanilla","chocolote","mango","Butterscotch"];
var data=[70,60,80,100];

for(var i=0;i<4;i++){


document.writeln("<tr><td id=\"dx\" width="+200+"px>type "+(i+1)+"</td><td width="+100+"px>"+type[i]+"</td><td>"+data[i]+"</td><td><input type=text></td><td id=a></td></tr>");

} 
document.writeln("<tr ></tr><td id=p1 colspan=4 style=\"text-align:right\">total</td><td ></td></table>");

function calculate() {
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
  const arrayInputValues = Array.from(inputs).map(input => +input.value);
  console.log(arrayInputValues);
}

function myfunc(){
  
}


//-->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--Bill.html-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Bill Payment</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1 style="text-align:center">The Ice-Cream Shop</h1>
<center>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script.js" >
</script>
<p><input type=button value=submit onclick="calculate()"> <input type=button value=clear onclick="myfunc()"></p>
<p id=x></p>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you can not get value in that input text, so you need to set id for input and use DOM to get value
`<input type='text' id='text"+ data[i] +"'>`

After that when you click button will use, and you can do anything after that.

> document.getElementByID('text1').value or `text2`... to get value